Loading vtk QML components in C++

I'm very new to VTK and I am on Windows 11. I've been trying to integrate VTK in QML. I have installed the VTK with Ninja using Cmake. However, when I want to use the components VTKRenderItem, I get Unknown component error. I have set the QML_IMPORT_PATH in the my CmakeLists.txt.
It's worth mentioning that import VTK 9.3 works fine, but when accessing the module's components, I get errors. (I have tested QML2_IMPORT_PATH as well, no chance)
The address of QML_IMPORT_PATH is set to cmake's default installation folder: Program files(x86)\VTK\lib\qml (I have copied the contents of this directory into my project's folder and made QML_IMPORT_PATH point to it. No chance!)

Any resolutions/suggestion would be highly appreciated
I expected the VTKRenderItem to be loaded and could be used, as I followed what was described in the official document of VTK for C++ (here is the site), but couldn't make it work.

If you want to render the VTK window in QML use QQuickVtkItem.
Here are examples from vtk:
https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/tree/master/Examples/GUI/QML?ref_type=heads
Here is another example
https://github.com/Joker-7-7/MultiViews

Inherit from QQuickVtkItem and override the initializeVTK() method

class MyVtkItem : public QQuickVtkItem
{
public:
    vtkUserData initializeVTK(vtkRenderWindow *renderWindow) override;
};


Сreate vtkObject data

struct MyVtkData : vtkObject
{
    static MyVtkData* New();
    vtkTypeMacro(MyVtkData, vtkObject);

    // Place all your persistant VTK objects here
};


Set up the scene, add objects and return data

QQuickVtkItem::vtkUserData MyVtkItem::initializeVTK(vtkRenderWindow *renderWindow)
{
    auto vtk = vtkNew<MyVtkData>();

    vtkNew<vtkNamedColors> colors;

    vtkNew<vtkRenderer> renderer;
    renderWindow->SetSize(640, 480);
    renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);

    vtkNew<vtkSphereSource> source;
    source->SetRadius(5.0);
    source->SetCenter(1, 1, 1);

    vtkNew<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper;
    mapper->SetInputConnection(source->GetOutputPort());
    vtkNew<vtkActor> actor;
    actor->SetMapper(mapper)
    actor->GetProperty()->SetColor(
            colors->GetColor3d("White").GetData());
    renderer->AddActor(actor);

    renderer->SetBackground(colors->GetColor3d("SteelBlue").GetData());
    return vtk;
}


Connect the item to QML (in main.cpp)

qmlRegisterType<MyVtkItem>("Vtk", 1, 0, "MyVtkItem");


Port the connection to the QML file

import Vtk 1.0 as Vtk


Create an item

    Vtk.MyVtkItem {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10
        opacity: 0.7
    }

